# permuting a df by rows with conditions within columns' values

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

Suppose I have a df like this one

```
df1 <- data.frame(n =c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9", "n10", "n11", "n12", "n13", "n14", "n15", "n16", "n17", "n18"), Cond1 =c("I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6"), Cond2 =c("c1", "c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2", "c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3"))
df1
```

and I sample by rows

```
df2 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
df2
```

I would like to set conditions for the sampling so that for example within the column Cond2 "c1" has a gap of a list one row before it occurs again in the following row.

Thus, I would like a random order of the rows but accessing the values of the columns, ordering that if in the previous row of the new df there is "c1" in cond2, the next row must not contain "c1", but "c2" or "c3".

Answer (score 2):

You could take a sample e.g. twice as long as `df1`. Then exploit the digits in your `Cond2` column to set a difference and delete all rows which difference is `0`. Finally shrink the data frame to the length of `df1`.

```
df2 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1), nrow(df1)*2, replace=TRUE), ]
df2$tmp <- diff(c(0, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df2$Cond2))))
df2[df2$tmp != 0, -4][1:nrow(df1), ]
#        n Cond1 Cond2
# 2     n2    I2    c1
# 8     n8    I2    c2
# 4     n4    I4    c1
# 12   n12    I6    c2
# 3.1   n3    I3    c1
# 13   n13    I1    c3
# 11   n11    I5    c2
# 5     n5    I5    c1
# 11.1 n11    I5    c2
# 14   n14    I2    c3
# 1     n1    I1    c1
# 18   n18    I6    c3
# 3.2   n3    I3    c1
# 8.1   n8    I2    c2
# 13.2 n13    I1    c3
# 10.1 n10    I4    c2
# 15   n15    I3    c3
# 1.1   n1    I1    c1
```

To adapt the solution for multiple columns you could use a `while` loop, because it is an iterative process with unknown length until all differences are `0`.

```
set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility
df2 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1), nrow(df1)*2, replace=TRUE), ]

df2$tmp1 <- diff(c(0, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df2$Cond1))))
df2$tmp2 <- diff(c(0, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df2$Cond2))))

while (any(df2[4:5] == 0)) {
  df2 <- df2[df2$tmp1 != 0, ]
  df2 <- df2[df2$tmp2 != 0, ]
  df2$tmp1 <- diff(c(0, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df2$Cond1))))
  df2$tmp2 <- diff(c(0, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df2$Cond2))))
}

df2
#        n Cond1 Cond2 tmp1 tmp2
# 17   n17    I5    c3    5    3
# 6     n6    I6    c1    1   -2
# 15   n15    I3    c3   -3    2
# 12   n12    I6    c2    3   -1
# 14   n14    I2    c3   -4    1
# 3     n3    I3    c1    1   -2
# 12.1 n12    I6    c2    3    1
# 13   n13    I1    c3   -5    1
# 9     n9    I3    c2    2   -1
# 13.1 n13    I1    c3   -2    1
# 9.1   n9    I3    c2    2   -1
# 17.3 n17    I5    c3    2    1
# 3.1   n3    I3    c1   -2   -2
# 18.1 n18    I6    c3    3    2
# 2     n2    I2    c1   -4   -2
# 10.1 n10    I4    c2    2    1
# 17.5 n17    I5    c3    1    1
# 9.3   n9    I3    c2   -2   -1
# 16   n16    I4    c3    1    1
# 7     n7    I1    c2   -3   -1
# 15.2 n15    I3    c3    2    1
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work!
what if I want also to logically combine the restrictions, like setting constraints both for Cond1 and Cond2?

And I want to decide the length of the gap of repetition in both columns?

So that I try if it can compute an order of the rows in which both Cond1 and Cond2 have values that never repeat in two adjacent rows, by 1 or by 2 rows for example.

Comment: @Mary I've extended the solution for no duplicates like you originally asked to two columns. Please consider to [mark the question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738) and [upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/371738) as a reward for the time I've spent.